# How to keep Javascript Clean

Tags: javascript

I am just starting out with javascript having worked with C# and OO languages for many years.

I am finding that I am putting my code in files like this,

```
database.js
sync.js
date.js
```

And it is feeling very procedural, basically just a bunch of public functions that can be called from anywhere. Can javascript be made to be object oriented, or cleaner than this?

To me it seems like this will become very large and messy quite easily.

Comment: First question is if those js files you posted all dont have anything in common I don't see anything wrong with seperate files.  You only combine the files if you are reusing various functions.  And yes of course js can be more object oriented.  Are you using js to perform operations on objects `var c = new Customer();` or are you using js to validate your pages?  Big difference there.

Answer (score 6):

Javascript is does not use "classical" object orientation in the way that you are use to, it uses a different object-orientation scheme labeled "Prototypal".  I suggest you read up on this to extract the most out of the strengths of the language.

http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Answer (score 3):

Sure it can, use a module build like [modul8](https://github.com/clux/modul8) or [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify)

Then rewrite your code like so

```
// date.js
var dateUtils = {
  ...
};

module.exports = dateUtils;

// database.js

var database = module.exports = {
  ...
};

// sync.js

var sync = module.exports = {
  ...
}

// main.js

var sync = require("./sync.js"),
    database = require("./database.js"),
    date = require("./date.js");

/* main body of code */
```

Of course if you want OO then use OO. JavaScript has prototypical OO, I have [a series about prototypical OO](http://raynos.org/blog/17/Improving-ES5-OO-with-sugar) that's worth reading.

And the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/1441105) illustrates a good pattern for OO.

Comment: Great posts on OO JS. +1 for `<!--[if lt IE 9]> go away <![endif]-->` on your blog! I do the same thing. Where's your doctype?

Comment: @ThinkingStiff I forgot I had that. As for the [DOCTYPE, its a bug](https://github.com/Raynos/trinity/issues/5)